# Postgresql-9.6 backup

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I have to backup a PostgreSQL database using this command:

`sudo pg_dumpall -a mydb > app111618.bak`

After I type that command, I get this error:

```
`pg_dumpall: too many command-line arguments (first is "mydb")`
```

In the command it say this:

> Try `pg_dumpall --help` for more information.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg_dumpall` is a tool to dump **all** databases, so it doesn't support specifying a database name (assuming that `mydb` is the name of the database you want to dump).

If you want to dump only a single database, use `pg_dump` instead:

```
pg_dump -a mydb > app111618.bak
```

If you did intend to dump all databases, just leave out the database name:

```
pg_dumpall -a > app111618.bak
```